# How to get Hazelcast map configuration

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I'm trying to create an API to get the Hazelcast map configuration. But when I tried to use

```
hazelcastInstance.getConfig().getMapConfig("MAP");
```

I'm getting an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client config object only supports adding new data structure configurations
```

any workaround to get the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround you can use the semi-internal API of Management Center (note: no backward-compatibility is guaranteed) to get the member config of a specific member, then you can parse it and extract the details you need.

Example:

```
    HazelcastClientInstanceImpl client = ((HazelcastClientProxy) HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient()).client;
    client.getMap("myMap").put(1, 2);
    Member aMember = client.getCluster().getMembers().iterator().next();
    ClientInvocation invocation = new ClientInvocation(
            client, // of type HazelcastClientInstanceImpl
            MCGetMemberConfigCodec.encodeRequest(),
            null,
            aMember.getUuid()
    );
    String config = new ClientDelegatingFuture<String>(
            invocation.invoke(),
            client.getSerializationService(),
            clientMessage -> MCGetMemberConfigCodec.decodeResponse(clientMessage).configXml
    ).get();
    MapConfig mapConfig = new XmlConfigBuilder(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).build().getMapConfig("myMap");
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.11, There is no MCGetMemberConfigCodec  :/

Comment: 1. I'm creating the map config in the client. 2. And I'm trying to read the same in Hazelcast member. But it is not found in the member.  Both should be in sync, right?